# Angular 2 routing that includes host file name?

Tags: javascript, angular

The situation is as follows:

- I have an Angular 2 app.
- The basic structure was generated using the
  most recent version of angular-cli.
- I have followed the documentation
  [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) with regard to routing.
- The app is not hosted at the root of the domain.
- I have `<base href="...">` set to the correct directory.
- The app is hosted from a file that is not named "index.html"

Basically, the route to the app is similar to "http://my.domain.com/dir1/dir2/hostfile.html"

Standard Angular 2 routing wants to route to "http://my.domain.com/dir1/dir2/" or "http://my.domain.com/dir1/dir2/route", dropping the file name completely, which results in a 404 error.

I cannot use "index.html" because it is already in use. I do not have access to change routing rules at the server level.

I remember in Angular 1 there was a way to make the routing include the host file, for example "http://my.domain.com/dir1/dir2/hostfile.html#/route".

Is there a away to set up my Angular 2 routing such that the host file name is included?

Comment: Have you set `<base href="...">` in your `index.html`?

Comment: Updated. Yes, base href is set. But, that seems to only control the directory. Can it control the file as well? I thought that would interfere with script loading.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I thought that could only control the directory, but I just tested it with the file name and it seems to work. Post that up as a solution so I can give you credit!

Comment: You can also provide `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/xxx/yyy'}`, then the setting doesn't interfere with scripts and other stuff (SVG, ...).